# How to get primary color of material theme in xml drawable?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to define round drawable which needs primary color of material theme. Here's my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"></solid>
</shape>
```

But I'm getting `InflateException`. I've read that we can not use attributes in drawable xml. So any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 39):

If you are using API 21 or greater, you should use:

```
<solid android:color="?android:colorPrimary"></solid>
```

For older APIs you should just type:

```
<solid android:color="?colorPrimary"></solid>
```

Comment: Little improvement here if you are looking forward to theme your app, try adding the color defined in colors.xml to to your app theme in styles.xml file like this, **<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myColorPrimary</item>
</style>** Now when you assign your theme color to the view (or any shape) in layouts, it would take the colorPrimary of current active theme.

Comment: I am using ?colorPrimary as a stroke color for a drawable that is being used as a background of RelativeLayout and when I add the background on runtime, the stroke just shows black. Even though colorPrimary is never black. And if I hardcode the hexadecimal code for color in drawable>XML file, it shows perfectly. Does anyone know how that can be fixed? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Is your colorPrimary stored in yours colors.xml? If so, just reference it like @color/colorPrimary.

If not, just define it in colors.xml and reference it. These are the default teal color of meterial straight from the source code. I think material_deep_teal_500 is what you are looking for.

```
<!-- Primary & accent colors -->

<color name="material_deep_teal_200">#ff80cbc4</color>
<color name="material_deep_teal_500">#ff009688</color>

<color name="material_blue_grey_800">#ff37474f</color>
<color name="material_blue_grey_900">#ff263238</color>
<color name="material_blue_grey_950">#ff21272b</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use attribute values in drawables.
You would be best to use a semi-transparent white/black (depending on if you are light or dark) like #44FFFFFF and overlaying over the primary color background. You'll notice most material drawables are a shade lighter/darker over a primary color background...

Otherwise, if you need the color duplicated - you will have to use @color/myPrimaryColor - which should be the same as what you defined in your theme as primaryColor.